# TIBCO RV: Listen to two networks at same time?

Tags: java, listener, tibco, tibco-rv

I have a test harness application that sends and listens for RV messages on our dev environment.  We have 2 separate RV networks (one for each building).  The test harness allows me to configure multiple senders, so I can set the service, network, & daemon correctly for each network and sure enough it sends to both.

The problem is with the listener.  It appears as there's only one place to put the listener info so I can only specify one buildings RV network.  Thus, when the message I'm looking for to pass a test occurs on opposite RV network, the listener doesn't hear it (even though it was correctly sent and appears in the logs) and thinks the test failed.

Is there any way to configure a single listener's service, network, and daemon in such a way that it can see both networks?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order enable cross-network communication with RV you need an additional (licensed) piece of software called "Rendezvous Routing Daemon".

Please have a look at the TIBCO documentation for more information: [RVRD](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/rendezvous/8.4.0-february-2012/doc/html/tib_rv_administration/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=tib_rv_administration&file=rv_adm.6.034.htm).